# Code in C# and build into cross platform binaries? (iOS and Android)

Tags: c#, java, android, iphone, cross-platform

As the question states, I am wondering if anyone is familiar with the ability to code in C#, and compile into IOS or Android native app-compatible binaries.

I know that Mono might be the answer here, but have never used it, and haven't seen anything around that allows me to take c# code and spit out seperate binaries, one of which would be compatible with IOS and on one with Android. Any thoughts?

I also know of Xamerin.iOS and Xamerin.Android, however these solutions look to be end to end solutions. I only want to code similar 'backend-ish' logic once, and give it to app developers to implement their native apps and just use the binary when necessary. I do not want the App to be cross platform built, just a simple logic binary in the back :)

Let me know if this is unclear, and I will try to be more clear :)

--EDIT: This is resolved as can't be done, as per the marked answer (and comments). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at [MonoCross](http://monocross.net/). But [Xamarin's](http://xamarin.com/) offerings really are second to none if you want to write Android/iOS apps in C#.

Comment: I don't want to write the entire App in Xamarin, just a few little Helper Libraries. Is this possible with Xamarin? I have done a little digging, but all I can find is full Apps made from Xamarin

Comment: No, it's not possible to write the app in Java & Objective C, but use code written in C#. Your only option is to abstract the C# business logic into a service and use Java/Objective-C to create the front-end user interface.

Comment: I am guessing you can't tell xamarin to output binaries to use in java/c apps? :D

Comment: I'm afraid not. As the name would indicate, both solutions use Mono which is a .NET runtime on top of the Android/iOS platforms. They do not produce native binaries.